# Is there a way to line up the y gridlines in a plotly scatter plot with 2 axes?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have a plot with two y axes and am trying to make the gridlines line up so that the ticks are on the same horizontal. I've tried using the same number of ticks with nticks, tried using tick0 and dtick to match up the lines, but nothing seems to work. Any insights?

The plot looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJJAb.png

Comment: can you show what you have tried? use `edit` button and show us some codes. thank you.

Comment: I have tried using nticks equal to the same number, and I have tried setting range of the red and blue data sets from -max(abs(data points of red and blue)) to max(abs(data points of red and blue)) to put 0 in the middle and the green set from 0 to max(green data points) with the same nticks.

Comment: I think I've got it figured out. This repository lays it out very well. https://github.com/VictorBezak/Plotly_Multi-Axes_Gridlines

Comment: When I've done this in the past I would manually calculate the ranges and tick locations so that these line up. Let me know if need an example!

Comment: Since 5.13, use https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#sync-axes-ticks